# How to obtain List filter's values in Aside object

Tags: react-admin

I would like to publish some info based on chosen filters into Aside on page based on List.

How can I push filter's values into Aside object?

```js
const Aside = ({ filters }) => {}
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Aside = ({ ...props }) => {
  console.log('props.filterValues:' + JSON.stringify(props.filterValues, null, 2));
```